# Blogger page navigation suddenly doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I'm using third party blogger theme for almost 6 months now, before this it works just fine, but i realize several days ago, page navigation doesn't seems to work anymore. when i click to "page 2". it just give me a loading gif and not loading the next page like it supposed to. I know nothing about coding, js etc, and totally clueless. could you help me with this?

This is the demo of my blog that currently having an issue, you can try click to "page 2" and see what happen.

http://hakhaktuhhei.blogspot.com/

full template : https://justpaste.it/xjdy

Comment: Please read the documentation on how to ask a question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, post the entire template code here.

Comment: Update with the entire template. I can't update the entire template above because it exceed the limits. so i paste it in the link that I provided instead.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript problem exist while onload action. Try to change theme entirely.